# Plotting multiple columns of different sizes with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm fairly new to Pandas, but typically what I do with data (when all columns are of equal sizes), I build np.zeros(count) matrices, then use a for loop to populate the data from a text file (np.genfromtxt()) to do my graphing and analysis in matplotlib.

However, I am now trying to implement similar analysis with columns of different sizes on the same plot from a CSV file.

For instance:

data.csv:

```
A  B  C  D  E  F 

1  2  3  4  5  6 

2 3 4 5 6 7

3 4 5 6

4 5


df = pandas.read_csv('data.csv')

ax = df.plot(x = 'A', y = 'B')

df.plot(x = 'C', y = 'D', ax = ax)

df.plot(x = 'E', y = 'F', ax = ax)
```

This code plots the first two on the same graph, but the rest of the information is lost (and there are a lot more columns of mismatched sizes, but the x/y columns I am plotting are the all the same size).

Is there an easier way to do all of this? Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused as to what you want the final result to look like.  Your code works for me.  I get a straight line as I would expect

Comment: I would like A-B, C-D, E-F, G-H, ...etc all plotted on one graph. The data is a lot of spectrums, so the x-axis varies, but not so much that it would be difficult to visualize. However, when I'm doing this with my actual data, it will only plot A-B, C-D and then stop. One thing to note is because this is a CSV, some of my imported data comes as NaN, so I'm not sure if that is impacting it or not...

Comment: Okay, I believe my issue is related to the NaN inputs after reading the CSV, so instead of the above data, the last two rows would look like:

3 4 5 6 NaN NaN

4 5 NaN NaN NaN NaN

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could generalize your solution :

I edited my answer to add an error handling. If you have a lonely last column, it'll still work.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = {
    'A' : [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'B' : [2, 3, 4, 5],
    'C' : [3, 4, 5, np.nan],
    'D' : [4, 5, 6, np.nan],
    'E' : [5, 6, np.nan, np.nan],
    'F' : [6, 7, np.nan, np.nan]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def Chris(df):
    ax = df.plot(x='A', y='B')
    df.plot(x='C', y='D', ax=ax)
    df.plot(x='E', y='F', ax=ax)
    plt.show()

def IMCoins(df):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    try:
        for idx in range(0, df.shape[1], 2):
            df.plot(x = df.columns[idx],
                    y = df.columns[idx + 1],
                    ax= ax)
    except IndexError:
        print('Index Error: Log the error.')

    plt.show()

Chris(df)
IMCoins(df)
```